# is there something like `rem` units for zoom/scale independent pixels?

Tags: css, units-of-measurement

Ideally there is some css specification coming down the pipe like an `rpx`.

when is an `em` not an em? when it is nested in an outer element that already has modified the font-size. and that's why there's `rem` units.

It seems like the same thing must be true with browser zoom, css zoom, and css transform/scale, relating to *pixels*.

right now in some of my scripts I find myself doing this:

```
jQuery('foo').css("zoom", my_custom_factor/jQuery('body').css("zoom"));
```

And frankly, that sucks. I could often instead specify a max-width and max-height in pixels .. but *the pixel units themselves* change with most if not all of those settings, and if zooms change, so do the pixels: Not only the zoom that I have control of as a programmer, but also the custom zoom that the user sets.

I only need an answer compatible with Chrome browser, as this mostly only applies to userscript. But extra koodoos if you have a general solution. *A possible solution that is not yet a css standard but is expected to be soon would count as an answer.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're not exactly "rpx", but maybe you're looking for something like [vw and vh](http://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/)?

Comment: in a perfect world this would work, but unfortunately vh and vw are influenced by zoom in chrome. in any case, if there is no rpx in the pipeline I should accept your answer.